# Is it necessary to have a parent component in an Angular route?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I'm currently reorganizing routes in my Angular app, I have a setup screen where I have multiple items that take me to a different route where the setting options are; e.g: The item "*User Management*" takes me to "*setup/user-management*", and inside this route I'm planning to build a sidebar with two options:

- Users
- Teams

Which each will have its own component (users-component, teams-component).

What I'm wondering is if I actually need a new component just to serve as a "middleground" between these two components in the route.

So far working with Angular I have always built a parent component to load in the route like:

```
{ path: 'setup/user-management', component: ParentComponent }
```

Then in that `ParentComponent`'s template I just put the other two components like:

```
<section>
   <users-component></users-component>
   <teams-component></teams-component>
</section>
```

But most of the time that component only serves as a place to put other components inside, it does nothing else; I wanted to know if there's a way to load a route without a specific component and build an interface without one; or if this is actually what I should always do.

I want to be clear, **I'm not asking if its better to do one thing or the other**, I actually want to know if Angular allows to access a route without a component and somehow render other components in that specific route, so I can avoid creating Parent components that do nothing more than containing the actual components that perform tasks.

Comment: [Route component](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#component) needs to be specified if [Route children](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#children) is not specified. The `component` specifies what template/HTML should be rendered when that route is matched, in your case specifically `<section>components</section>`. Is the alternative you are looking for is to just specify a `template` inline, similar to what you can in a `Component`? Like `{ path: 'setup/user-management', template: '<section>foo</section>' }`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thats kinda what I'm trying, to avoid creating a new component which will only serve as a simple container for the components I actually need in that route, can I use something like `template` in the route object?